# Nesting multiple models with cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, model-associations, cocoon-gem

I'm trying to create nested form which will combine 2 attributes for two associated models.

Let's say I have 3 models: Recipe (main model), RecipeIngredient (join model for recipe and ingredients) and Ingredient.

Code is below:

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :directions, inverse_of: :recipe
    has_many :recipe_ingredients, inverse_of: :recipe
    has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients,
                                    reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? },
                                    allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :directions,
                                    reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['step'].blank? },
                                    allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_ingredients,
                                    reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['quantity'].blank? },
                                    allow_destroy: true


    validates :tittle, :description, :image, presence: true
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "400x400#" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :recipe_ingredient, inverse_of: :ingredient
    has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_ingredient
end
class RecipeIngredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient, inverse_of: :recipe_ingredient

end
```

My nesting:

```
.col-md-6
                %h3 Skladniki
                #ingredients
                    = f.simple_fields_for :recipe_ingredients do |recipe_ingredient|
                        =render 'recipe_ingredient_fields', f: recipe_ingredient
                    .links
                        = link_to_add_association 'Dodaj skladnik', f, :recipe_ingredients, class: "btn btn-default add-button", :wrap_object => Proc.new {|recipe_ingredient| recipe_ingredient.build_ingredient; recipe_ingredient }
```

Here you can see see that I'm trying to access two attributes:
1. quantity (of class RecipeIngredient) - this part is ok
2. name (of class Ingredient) - this part is completly KO

```
.form-inline.clearfix
        .nested-fields
            = f.input :quantity, :label => "Ilość", input_html: { class: "form-input form-control" }
            = f.fields_for :ingredients_attributes do |ingr|
                = ingr.input :name, :label => "Nazwa", input_html: { class: "form-input form-control" }

            = link_to_remove_association "Usun", f, class: "form-button btn btn-default"
```

During validation I get this error

> Recipe ingredients ingredient must exist

And here is why:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nw14a3HkgSrjE+QpIK4POEzTOqBhtE/EMe+CarWkmI6CSRf0GAdWZGzJQRD4aPurNDNm96TJbt60mc1hl+1JPA==", "recipe"=>{"tittle"=>"Tosty", "description"=>"Testowy przepis", "preparation_time"=>"10.0", "portion"=>"2", "recipe_ingredients_attributes"=>{"1507996685991"=>{"quantity"=>"432", "ingredients_attributes"=>{"name"=>"fasdd"}, "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1507996689888"=>{"quantity"=>"2134432342", "ingredients_attributes"=>{"name"=>"dsad"}, "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "directions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"step"=>"Krok1", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"step"=>"Krok2", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"2"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Recipe", "id"=>"5"}
  Recipe Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: ingredients_attributes
Unpermitted parameter: ingredients_attributes
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  Direction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "directions".* FROM "directions" WHERE "directions"."recipe_id" = ? AND "directions"."id" IN (1, 2)  [["recipe_id", 5]]
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
```

arguments passed to method just dont match definition of recipe_params (private method in recipe_controller):

```
def recipe_params
        params.require(:recipe).permit(:tittle, :description, :image, :portion, :preparation_time, ingredients_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy], directions_attributes: [:id, :step, :_destroy], recipe_ingredients_attributes: [:id, :quantity, :_destroy])
    end
```

The point is ... how to fix it?so the ingredients_attributes will be passed out of recipe_ingredients_attributes?

Answer (score 1):

The error in the logfile states that the `ingredients_attributes` parameter is not allowed. If you check the passed parameters you can see that the `recipe_ingredients_attributes` contains the `ingredients_attributes` and this is not allowed by your strong parameters definition (the `recipe_params` method): it has to support the correct nesting as well.

Comment: I know where is the problem. The point is that I dont know how to fix that.
Before I used nested form with quantity attribute included in Ingredient model. But for functionality I had to add join model and now I dont know how to generate properly assiociated controls for Ingredient :name and RecipeIngredient :quantity

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nathan.

Answer for this can be driectly found here (cocoon git):
https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/461